# Не выполняется команда "php yii"

Tags: php, yii2

Дело такое: есть проект на yii2. В нем все модули программы были помещены в папку vendor, из-за чего нельзя было пользоваться composer. Я вынес все модули из вендора, поправил конфиги, программа работает. Хотел накатить новые миграции, но при вызове "php yii migrate" ничего не происходило. Позже выяснил что он не реагирует ни на одну команду "php yii ...". Если вернуть модули обратно в вендор и конфиги, то всё работает нормально.

В командной строке выглядит вот так:

```
root@vm:/var/www/mysite.ru# php yii

root@vm:/var/www/mysite#
```

Comment: хотя бы код возврата команды покажите.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 255

Comment: просто число 255?

Comment: "из-за чего нельзя было пользоваться composer." --- в смысле нельзя? композер как раз и работает с вендором и всё настроено на это. поэтому менять путь будет ошибкой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я новичок в пользовании линуксом. Я так понял код возврата это "echo $?" после выполнения команды. А так если команду в консоли пишешь, то он ошибок не выкидывает, просит ввести следующую команду, как будто выполнилось успешно. А композер нельзя было использовать потому что на composer update он бы переписал все, а там и autoload кастомный был. Проект изначально не мой, поэтому я только исправляю эту ситуацию.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский модули я вынес из вендора в backend/modules, настроил кастомные namespace в composer.json, поправил пути к модулям в конфигах. И сам сайт работает отлично, все модули отрабатывают как надо, но на попытке залить новые мирации пришёл к вышеописанной проблеме.

Comment: @DaniilTsarenok Это надо смотреть скорее сам проект и структуру. Так сложно сказать. Возможно дело в настройках. Возможно у вас вообще сам файл yii в какой-либо папке, а не в корне. Т.к. там всё перестроено относительно стандарта - ничего точного, кроме самого реорганизатора (кто занимался проектом) мне кажется мало кто чем сможет помочь

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена дебагом методом "echo 1" после каждой строчки в файле yii.php. Проблема оказалась банальная: в консольном конфиге в одном из пути к конфигу модуля был лишний символ, из-за чего в переменной $config был неправильный путь.

Comment: [Как находить ошибки в PHP коде - Debugging (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482) --- если ещё не освоили - рекомендую)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, обязательно ознакомлюсь :)